# MySql - Count by Month with 2 different dates in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project in order to count the number of incidents opened and closed per months. 
I've a sql DB on which the records are. 
I'm trying to write a SQL request to count the number of incidents Opened and Closed each month.

So far I'm able to count the number of incidents opened as below:

```
   SELECT
    YEAR (`startDate`),
    MONTH (`startDate`),
    COUNT(id) AS Opened
FROM
    incidents
GROUP BY
    YEAR (`startDate`),
    MONTH (`startDate`)
```

Here is an exemple of the table I've:

[image]

And the result What I need.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please include code that you've tried, and specific problems you're having. Don't link to images when you can reproduce the data in text within your question.

Answer (score 0):

select MONTHNAME(startdate),count(MONTH(startdate)),count(MONTH(enddate)) from test GROUP BY month(startdate);

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below query. Hope it should be solved your problem.

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(start_date) as Month,
    COUNT(start_date) as CountStartDate,
    COUNT(end_date) as CountEndDate
FROM
    incidents
GROUP BY
    MONTHNAME(start_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT
    YEAR (`startDate`),
    MONTH (`endDate`),
    COUNT(id) AS Opened
FROM
    incidents
WHERE
    YEAR (`startDate`)= YEAR (`endDate`)
    MONTH (`startDate`)= MONTH (`endDate`)
GROUP BY
    YEAR (`startDate`),
    MONTH (`endDate`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT
    Month(startDate) as Month,
    COUNT(startDate) as startDate,
    COUNT(endDate) as countEndDate
FROM
    incidents
GROUP BY
    Month(startDate)`

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want in the correct order as well. Hope it helps

```
SELECT
    YEAR('startDate'),
    DATENAME(Month,'startDate'),
    COUNT(*)
FROM incidents
GROUP BY 
    YEAR('startDate'),  
    MONTH('startDate'),
    DATENAME(Month,'startDate')
ORDER BY 
    YEAR('startDate'),
    MONTH('startDate')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this worked.

```
CREATE TABLE abcd 
    SELECT 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=1, 1, 0)) s_1, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=2, 1, 0)) s_2, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=3, 1, 0)) s_3, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=4, 1, 0)) s_4, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=5, 1, 0)) s_5, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=6, 1, 0)) s_6, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=7, 1, 0)) s_7, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=8, 1, 0)) s_8, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=9, 1, 0)) s_9, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=10, 1, 0)) s_10, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=11, 1, 0)) s_11, 
        sum(if(month(start_date)=12, 1, 0)) s_12,
        sum(if(month(end_date)=1, 1, 0)) e_1, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=2, 1, 0)) e_2, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=3, 1, 0)) e_3, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=4, 1, 0)) e_4, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=5, 1, 0)) e_5, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=6, 1, 0)) e_6, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=7, 1, 0)) e_7, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=8, 1, 0)) e_8, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=9, 1, 0)) e_9, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=10, 1, 0)) e_10, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=11, 1, 0)) e_11, 
        sum(if(month(end_date)=12, 1, 0)) e_12  
    FROM incidents;

SELECT s_1 start, e_1 end, 'Jan' month FROM abcd 
UNION SELECT s_2 start, e_2 end, 'Feb' month FROM abcd 
UNION SELECT s_3 start, e_3 end, 'Mar' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_4 start, e_4 end, 'Apr' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_5 start, e_5 end, 'May' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_6 start, e_6 end, 'Jun' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_7 start, e_7 end, 'Jul' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_8 start, e_8 end, 'Aug' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_9 start, e_9 end, 'Sep' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_10 start, e_10 end, 'Oct' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_11 start, e_11 end, 'Nov' month FROM abcd
UNION SELECT s_12 start, e_12 end, 'Dec' month FROM abcd;

DROP TABLE abcd;
```